# ACF field from theme options

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have WordPress website with ACF plugin. I have created Theme option page using

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Theme General Settings',
        'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
        'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
        'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));
}
```

Also I created Theme Option Field Group | header ( Group ) | header_logo ( sub field )

So my structure

```
- theme options ( options field group )
-- header ( field type - group | field name - header )
--- header_logo ( subfield )
```

and I try to show  header logo in header

```
<?php
if (have_rows('header', 'option')) :
    while (have_rows('header_logo', 'option')) : the_row();
        $header_logo = get_sub_field('header_logo');
        if ($header_logo) {
            echo '<img src="' . esc_url($header_logo['url']) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($header_logo['alt']) . '">';
        }
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

But this code returns nothing - neither an error nor a value

Comment: What have you tried with debugging? Does [`get_row()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row/) have any value?